# How to manage misalignments between Design Specs and After Design Adjustments?

Tags: scrum, jira, documentation, design, specification

How do you manage this scenario?

- UX and Visual design a feature.
- PO and DEV decided -after design got approved- to ignore some specs of implementation, so we have something different than the design specs.

Where should be located this information?
Because SM ended up with a stakeholder discussion (PO is sick) and after his check of JIRA ticket he saw design and website implementation not aligned. After having created a bug a DEV told him that it was discussed with PO to be implemented like this. So the different design implementation is not reported anywhere.

In my opinion these (ignored) specs update should stay in the design page (Zeplin, Confluence, whatever…). Do you agree? Because otherwise for anyone who losts that info, this scenario may look like a BUG. The missing part then could be turned into a new FEATURE, with again added comments.

Do you agree? What do you think?

Comment: One obvious miscommunication is that the stakeholder was not kept in the loop when the PO decided to ignore some parts of the specs. This is independent of if/where the change should be documented.

Comment: [The Scrum Guide](http://scrumguides.org/) and [Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your organisation uses Jira tickets as their central source of information, (i.e your SM looks at Jira tickets), so the Jira tickets should contain short comments on how the implementation decisions have changed, and why.

Put a link in the ticket that points to the appropriate design directory. This way the ticket *always* references the most recent version of the visual design.

As you say, in an ideal world, the design itself should have been reworked, or at least annotated, to point out the features that would be delivered at different times....but that's seldom possible in a fast-paced workplace.

Definitely turn the "leftover" or de-prioritised features into separate stories for the backlog. And mark them as related to the original story, for continuity.

Comment: JIRA is our backlog, but in our company we have also Zeplin for our design projects. So I think that, once a JIRA ticket is solved and disappears from the backlog, those JIRA notes might be lost.
That's why I think Zeplin or Confluence could be a good place to write down those info.

Comment: @axel In my view,  it never hurts to write a few words in a ticket to describe a change. 

Yes, if your organisation has the bandwidth to re-do the design/ design notes, and you have the authority to instruct the design department to do that, the design area is the best place. It's not always feasible, though.

Comment: don't get me wrong, JIRA tickets can also contain those info, specially during the progress of the ticket from OPEN to DONE, but in my opinion it is not enough. I asked the question because about this topic I heard many ways to take care of it, so I put my question here as well.